# Google Spreadsheet Apps Script: Dialog box from HTML Service not loading when embedded

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, embed

I am having an issue where I created a custom dialog that displays some very basic HTML output using the HTML Service. This works well in Google Sheets, but when I embed the editable google sheet into another website, the content will not load.

Using the inspector/console, I have learned that the issue may be related to "Refused to display {link} in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'." I have referenced https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions and believe I have followed all relevant instructions, but I have been unable to resolve this issue for a few weeks now

I am not a developer, just dabbling, so even just resources to learn more about how to approach this issue would be very welcome.

Below is my code.  Thank you for your time!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    Hello, world! <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
  </body>
</html>
```

GS:

```
function showDialog() {
   var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('showDialogPage')
   .setWidth(400)
   .setHeight(300)
   .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);


SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
    .showModalDialog(html, 'My custom dialog');
}
```

Comment: this "other website", is it https?

Comment: Liora, yes it is https. I said other website simply because I have tried embedding in a few and have had no luck, but happy to provide specifics if it helps!